# I'm trying to make Alexa skills for raspberry pi, but AMAZON.LITERAL is no longer available

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

Trying to finish off my magic mirror using Alexa, ive taken enough work arounds to get past the other changes amazon has mad, however i cannot complete the skill I am creating as I am not offered AMAZON.LITERAL when creating slots for the intents. It is also very tedious typing the intents line by line in the, I would much prefer typing the code out itself;

```
{
    "intent": "ShowSelectImageIntent",
    "slots": [{
      "name": "searchTerm",
      "type": "AMAZON.LITERAL"
    }]
}
```

rather than using the dropdown boxes is it still possible to simply do the required code manually? If so how, if not is there a way to bypass or at least imitate the AMAZON.LITERAL effect? I read of custom slots which supposedly allow this, but I simply cannot find nor access these slots.

thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the AMAZON.SearchQuery slot type. https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#amazonsearchquery

Comment: I did look at it, but it only takes questions, it doesn't do commands such as "display "how are you today" on the screen like LITERAL did", I can only get half of what I am after out of it.